# Doubt in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics

If one dependent variable is in percentage form and the other is in plain numerical form, is there a need for transformation of the variables?

This is specific to multiple regression.

Comment: What is your dependent variable (your $y$)?

Comment: what does "plain numerical form" mean? could you give an example of "non-plain numerical form"?

Answer (score 2):

If the dependent variable is in percentage and ranges from 0 to 100, then you might not want OLS regression at all. Consider beta regression.

OLS regression makes certain assumptions. One of those is that the errors are distributed normally. When the dependent variable is bounded, this assumption is unlikely to be valid (although it can be checked).

Beta regression assumes a bounded dependent variable.

Another alternative is to take the arcsin transformation, which is the arcsin of the square root of the proportion. This was popular before beta regression was well-known. The problem is interpreting the result.

Comment: No, that's outside the scope of my current studies. In OLS, what can we do then?

Comment: @user585380 Probably best is to hire a consultant.  You may need an expert.  Alternatively, you could try the arcsine transformation.